# How can I prevent dragged items to be drawn during a drag and drop operation in Qt?

Tags: qt

When draggin items from a QListView, the dragged items are drawn along with the mouse cursor and drop indicator. How can I prevent this behavior and just get the drop indicator? I am dragging from huge list items into small targets, and this makes things pretty difficult to target as the drop area is hidden by the huge dragged items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually if i do not explicitly call drag->setPixmap() i don't have a visible dragged item (Win XP). Probably you should just call QDrag::setPixmap() with a scaled down Version of the dragged Object.

Comment: Indeed, this method is called by QAbstractItemView when a drag operation is started. Looks like I will have to override this method in order to implement the desired behavior. Thanks a lot for the pointer, this is exactly what I needed!